# Best practice to load UI components in an activity

Tags: android, android-layout

Is there a convention or best practice to bind UI elements to variables in activities? I'd typically do something like:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        loadElements();
    }

private void loadElements(){

button1=(Butotn)findViewByID(R.id.button1);
txV1=(TextView)findViewByID(R.id.texview1);

 }
```

Somewhere i read that findViewByID() can be taxing. Is this true?

Comment: try not to call findviewbyid() more than one time for a view unless you have to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While there's not really an convention, you may consider using library called [ButterKnife](https://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) (there are some other too, but this one seem most popular), that would do this for you without a need of writing all this boring boilerplate code. So your code could be downsized to look just like this:

```
@Bind(R.id.button1)
Button button1;

@Bind(R.id.texview1)
TextView txV1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
}
```

Comment: While butterknife is an awesome library (kudos to Jake Wharton), this is not a convention at all. More a "some people like to use it", also AFAIK it uses `@Bind()`

Comment: True, it's not a convention. Let me edit the answer :)